# Можно ли считать, что подобная архитектура написана с использованием паттерна MVP?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Изучаю паттерн MVP.

Используя различные примеры из интернета, написал свой небольшой проект с MVP.

Проект простой:

- Одна форма
- Два DataGridView.

В одном выводится список клиентов из базы данных, в другом выводится список счетов конкретного клиента.

Хотел узнать.

- Полностью ли выдержан данный паттерн в проекте?
- Или же есть какие-то замечания?

Код проекта ниже:

Форма ClientForm:

```
public partial class ClientForm : Form, IClientView
{
    public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataGridView ClientDgv { get => Clients_dataGridView; }
    public DataGridView AccountsDgv { get => Accounts_dataGridView; }

    private void LoadClients_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientPresenter p = new ClientPresenter(this, new ClientModel());
        p.LoadClients();
    }

    private void LoadAccounts_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int clientCode = Convert.ToInt32(ClientDgv.CurrentRow.Cells["ClientCode"].Value.ToString());

        ClientPresenter p = new ClientPresenter(this, new ClientModel());
        p.LoadAccounts(clientCode);
    }
}
```

IClientView:

```
public interface IClientView
{

    DataGridView ClientDgv { get; }

    DataGridView AccountsDgv { get; }

}
```

ClientPresenter:

```
public class ClientPresenter
{
    private ClientModel _clientModel;
    private IClientView _clientView;
    private readonly DBConnection _conn = DBConnection.GetInstance("C:\\DB\\Database.FDB", true);

    public ClientPresenter(IClientView view, ClientModel model)
    {
        _clientView = view;
        _clientModel = model;
    }

    public void LoadClients()
    {
        string selectClientsQuery = "SELECT * FROM Clients";
        _conn.ExecuteQuery(selectClientsQuery);
        _clientModel.ClientDt = _conn.ResultAsDataTable();
        _clientView.ClientDgv.DataSource = _clientModel.ClientDt;
    }

    public void LoadAccounts(int clientCode)
    {
        string selectAccountsQuery = $"SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE ClientCode = {clientCode}";
        _conn.ExecuteQuery(selectAccountsQuery);
        _clientModel.AccountsDt = _conn.ResultAsDataTable();
        _clientView.AccountsDgv.DataSource = _clientModel.AccountsDt;
    }
}
```

ClientModel:

```
public class ClientModel
{
    public DataTable ClientDt;
    public DataTable AccountsDt;
}
```

Comment: У вас получилось не совсем то, ну или совсем не то). UI напрямую завязан на презентер(хотя по идее не должен о нем знать) Презенер содержит всю бизнес-логику, хотя как это должно быть в модели(например обращение к базе). Ну и анимичная модель вообще без логики. Посмотрите вот эти статьи https://habr.com/ru/post/215605/  и https://habr.com/ru/post/211899/

Comment: В статье Википедии написано следующее: "Представитель (англ. Presenter) — реализует взаимодействие между Моделью и Видом **и содержит в себе всю бизнес-логику**". И что Вы подразумеваете под "анимичная модель"? Если это View, то какая логика там должна присутствовать на Ваш взгляд?

Comment: Анемичная модель - модель содержащая только данные, без логики. Сейчас она  достаточно популярна. Обычно сервисы содержат всю бизнес-логику, а модели - это всего лишь данные. Класическая модель - данные и бизнес-логика. Обратите внимание на первую мою ссылку, там хорошо описана схема MVP с класической моделью. Я не знаю что там в вики, но презентер это совсем не место для бизнес-логики, да могут быть некоторые исключения, но это исключения...

Comment: Вся суть паттернов MVC, MVP, MVVM... какие там еще есть. Сводится к устранению жестких связей между UI и бизнес логикой. Презентер MVP или контроллер в MVC это по сути посредник, как раз за счет которого и происходит это раздедение. Ну а вы в коде засунли логику в презентер и жестко привязали его к UI, где тут разделение ?

Comment: Но где же прослеживается эта жёсткая связь, если я в Презентере с UI взаимодействую не напрямую, а с помощью интерфейса? В данном случае, UI лишь реализует этот интерфейс. Презентер даже не знает о том, какой тип передаётся в конструкторе.

Comment: Либо отдавайте в UI через конструктор интерфейс IClientPresenter, тогда ваша вьюха перестанет напрямую зависить от реализации презентера. Или добавьте в ваш IClientView события для ваших кнопок и события кнопки транслируйте в презентер через них. Кстати во второй статье есть ссылка на пример https://github.com/Dem0n13/MVPWinFormsDemo

Comment: На мой взгляд, все у вас правильно, логика в презентере возможна, только работу с БД следует выделять в отдельный класс репозитория. Связь через интерфейс с вьюхой - это правильно и именно в презентер нужно передавать интерфейс вьюхи,  а не так как вам советовал @PavelPopov.

Comment: @Bulson и презентер нужно создавать в каждом методе, а не инжектить через конструктор, через интерфейс ?

Comment: @PavelPopov нет, конечно. Там же есть `private IClientView _clientView;` и передача через ctor. Так что я не понимаю о чем вы...?

Comment: @Bulson да интерфейс вьюхи он отдает в перзентер, прекрасно, хотя я не согласен что презентер должен содержать всю логику, а модель это просто класс с данными... В коде вьюхи, в двух обрабочиках он создает ClientPresenter, это верно по вашему ?

Comment: @PavelPopov да, здесь вы правы, я проглядел. Это конечно не правильно, надо было события нажатий на кнопки пробрасывать в презентер и там работать с этими событиями.

Comment: более-менее вменяемое [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6RNy3rPZpg) по этой теме на русском языке.

Comment: @Bulson ну так у меня и было две претензии по сути ) 1. вьюха напрямую владеет презентаром 2.  презентер владеет всей логикой. Да конечно в нем бывает логика, но это скорее искючение чем правило

Comment: Хотелось бы подвести итоги. Паттерн почти выполняется. Необходимо лишь сделать следующее: а) Добавить обработчики события, а в презентере подписаться на них, и реализовать логику; б) По мнению Pavel Popov необходимо перенести работу с базой данных в компонент Model. @Pavel Popov, Вы с этим согласны или же ещё что-нибудь добавите?